# Android Test a function is being called on Scroll

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have this ScrollChangedListener

```
var scrolledOnce = false
 scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(object : View.OnScrollChangeListener{
            override fun onScrollChange(
                v: View?,
                scrollX: Int,
                scrollY: Int,
                oldScrollX: Int,
                oldScrollY: Int
            ) {

              if(!scrolledOnce) {
                  scrolledOnce = true
                  handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
                      scrolledOnce = false
                      isCalled()
                  }, 1000)
              }

            }

        })
```

This is the test for that

```
@get:Rule
    var activityScenarioRule = activityScenarioRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun checkScrollEvent(){

        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.scrollVw)).perform(ViewActions.swipeDown())

    }
```

I want to verify that isCalled() was being called. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to swipe up on the scroll view not down.

```
onView(withId(R.id.scrollVw).performViewActions.swipeUp())

onView(withText("The next item").check(matches(isDispalyed())
```